# plot displaying straight line as ramp - Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I have a list y. When I plot it without x axis, it works fine:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
plt.plot(y)
```

[image: Correct Plot]

As you can see, all the data in list y is a straight line and there is no ramp. 
However, when I try to plot the *same y* on a scaled x axis, it displays ramps.

```
x_axis=range(60*24)
x_axis=np.divide(x_axis,60)
plt.plot(x_axis,y)
```

[image: Wrong Plot]

Why is it so?

> **EDIT:** if it helps, my list y is :

```
  print(y)
[0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 20.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 677.0, 677.0, 677.0, 677.0, 677.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 21.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 1734.0, 1734.0, 1734.0, 1734.0, 1734.0, 1734.0, 761.0, 761.0, 761.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 901.0, 140.0, 140.0, 140.0, 140.0, 140.0, 140.0, 140.0, 140.0, 140.0, 140.0, 140.0, 140.0, 140.0, 140.0, 140.0, 140.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 913.0, 913.0, 913.0, 913.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 121.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
```

Comment: X - values are not consistent or continuous check them if there are any missing values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume your original data has a value every minute, so you have directly minutes on your y axis when you just do `plt.plot(y)` and you want to scale the y-axis from minutes to hours. To match your minutes exactly with the corresponsing hours, I would rather do

```
x_axis = np.linspace(0,24,1440)
```

so your first entry will be at 0 and the last at 24:

```
array([0.00000000e+00, 1.66782488e-02, 3.33564976e-02, ...,
       2.39666435e+01, 2.39833218e+01, 2.40000000e+01])
```

For me this results in:

[image]